# Population clustering from Raster using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, clustering, population

I have a raster image with different pixel values, each one representing the number of people living in the pixel. I want to cluster the pixels based on the sum of the pixel values equaling 1000 in each cluster. I do not expect an exact sum for each cluster, but I aim for the sum value to be close to 1000. I have tried using a vector point format and then converted it into raster format to experiment with this approach.

I have converted the vector points into a raster and assigned the attribute data to the pixels. As a result, the raster only contains pixels where there were originally points."

I am using ArcMap 10.7.

I am also fine with vector based cluster for this as well.

Comment: I have a confusion. "Clustering based on the sum of the pixel values = 1000": does it mean that pixels totalling 1000 will be a cluster?

Comment: no i meant that pixel value (number of people representing the pixel) will need to be clustered. for ex (1 pixel represent 4 peoples. so i need the sum of the population equaling to 1000,  so the number of pixel will be below 1000)

Comment: How big is your raster?

Comment: bit confused you are asking about the size of the raster or the area of the raster that representing? size of the raster about 16 KB and  area of the raster all together about 15km2. but i have 20 separate raster's created based on the local boundary. but the raster only contains pixels where there were originally points.

Comment: When i asked raster size, I meant cells count, because I have vector based solution but it can't handle many Ks of features

Comment: number of columns and rows is 1141*2449 and cell size is 3 by 3 meter. so the total cell count will be 2, 794,309 pixels. i have mosaic the raster into one and now i have pixels where the originally doesn't have a point value.

Comment: Hi all, i got and answer for what i searching for. tool called Build Balanced Zones under mapping cluster will do the task.